# Alternative proof Hall's marriage explanation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have read an alternative proof of Hall's marriage theorem in the book "Combinatorial Optimization Polyhedra and Efficiency" by Alexander Schrijver but I do not understand well what is going on in the proof.

I report here the definitions and the proof of the sufficiency of the Hall's condition as given in the book above.

First some notation.

1. Let $A_1,\dots,A_n$ be a family of sets. A transversal (of $A_1,\dots,A_n$) is a set of distinct elements $a_1 \in A_1,\dots,a_n \in A_n$.
2. If $I \subset \{1,\dots,n\}$ then $A_I := \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$.

Hall's theorem (sufficiency Hall's condition): If $|A_I| \geq |I|$ for each subset $I$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ then there exists a transversal.

Proof:
Call a subset $I$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ tight if $|A_I|=|I|$.
If there is a $y \in A_n$ such that $A_1 \setminus \{y\},\dots,A_{n-1}\setminus\{y\}$ has a transversal, then we have done.
Hence, we may assume that for each $y \in A_n$ there is a tight $I \subset \{1,\dots,n-1\}$ with $y \in A_I$ (using induction).

Choose any such tight subset $I$. Witouth loss of generality, $I = \{1,\dots,k\}$.
By induction, $A_1,\dots,A_k$ has a transversal, which must be $T:=A_I$.
Moreover, $A_{k+1}\setminus T,\dots,A_n \setminus T$ has a transversal, $Z$ say.
This follows inductively, since for each $J \subset \{k+1,\dots,n\}$, $|\bigcup_{i \in J} (A_i \setminus T) | = | \bigcup_{i \in I \cup J} A_i | - |T| \geq |I|+|J|-|T|=|J|$.
Then $T \cup Z$ is a transversal of $A_1,\dots,A_k,A_{k+1},\dots,A_n$. This concludes the proof.

It seems that there is a sort of induction going on but I cannot see the whole picture.
In particular why this statement "Hence, we may assume that for each $y \in A_n$ there is a tight $I \subset \{1,\dots,n-1\}$ with $y \in A_I$ (using induction)." is true?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proof is by induction on (let's say) $n$.

> Hence, we may assume that for each $y \in A_n$ there is a tight $I \subset \{1,\dots,n-1\}$ with $y \in A_I$ (using induction).

Suppose that some $y \in A_n$ is not contained in any tight set. You should verify that this implies that $A_1 \setminus \{y\},\ldots,A_{n-1} \setminus \{y\}$ satisfies Hall's condition. By induction, there is a transversal, which you can extend to a transversal of $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ by adding $y$.

This type of proof is common in certain areas of graph theory: we show that if there is no tight set, then we can reduce the problem to a smaller one in one way, and if there is a tight set, then we can "cut along the tight set" to reduce the problem in another way.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification of the highlighted statement. But I do not understand what is the role of this statement in the proof since the fact that $y \in A_n$ is also in $y \in A_I$ for the tight set $I$ seems to not be necessary.

Comment: You are right, the wording of the proof is not optimal. The only thing that is used is that there is *some* tight set. So it is enough to consider a single $y \in A_n$ and show that either there is a tight set (containing it, but that's not important), or $y$ and $A_n$ can be deleted.